# Handling array with PHP into MySQL from JavaScript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I am creating an array, which contains data from a table.

```
var myarray = [];

$.each(multi, function (index, item) {
    myarray.push( {name: 'ticket_row_num', 
                   value: $(item).data('ticket_row_num')
                } ); 
    myarray.push( {name: 'itemtitle', value: $(item).data('itemtitle')} );
    myarray.push( {name: 'row_itemid', value: $(item).data('row_itemid')} ); 
    myarray.push( {name: 'row_quantity', value: $(item).data('row_quantity')} ); 
    myarray.push( {name: 'rowunitprice', value: $(item).data('rowunitprice')} );  
    myarray.push( {name: 'row_total', value: $(item).data('row_total')} ); 
    myarray.push( {name: 'measure_type_is_grams', 
                   value: $(item).data('measure_type_is_grams')
                } ); 

});
```

I then post this to PHP via AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,  
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        myarray:myarray,
        unique_reference:unique_reference,
        tablenumber:tablenumber
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
        // alert("before send");
    },
    success: function(html) {
        alert(html);                        
    }
});
```

I am having trouble inserting the data into MySQL correctly. I need to handle the array in the correct way to insert the correct values into the database at the correct time.

**The PHP**

```
 $array = $_POST['myarray'];
 if (is_array($array)){
    foreach($array as $item){
        //  $name = $item['name'].$n;
        $value = $item['value'].$n.$n;

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO sales_tickets(value) values('{$value}')");
    }
```

The issue is that this array is returning all of the values in a row. 
`How can I manage this array better, so that each of the 7 values are inserted to a row respective of their rows?`

**The MySQL Table**
[image: The MySQL Table]

Comment: you quote the whole `'{$value}'` . try it without like `"INSERT ... values({$value})");`

Comment: Please describe the fields in your table `sales_tickets` and how they relate to the field in the array!

Comment: are you grabbing data from a html table and then post data in MySQL Database?

Comment: im grabbing strings stored in `data-` attributes within the `tr` of each row. Each row needs to be inserted to the mysql table respectively.